# A TextView change applies to multiple TextViews using ListView and ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, textview

I've started working on a small project not to long ago, the main goal is to forge a way for me to keep track of my actions during the course of 100 weeks.

I'm still a rookie android developer and I've encountered an issue that I couldn't explain.

Basically I've populated a ListView using the ArrayAdapter with a list containing 100 strings (Week1, Week2, Week3 ... Week100)

Setting up an onclicklistener on each of the TextViews so that when a user performs a click on a textview, the background color would change to red.

However; whenever I click a single textview - more than a single textview is being colored.

Notes:

1. I'm using a ScrollView to scroll through the entire list. (Once populated, the 100 week list fills up the entire screen, the scroll view is used to access the entire list.)
2. I also saved a reference to the currently painted textview so I could make sure that when a user clicks a different textview, the previous one would lose its red background.

MainActivity initialization:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
TextView selectedWeek; // Reference to the selected week.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    populateWeekList(); // Populating the ListView
    initWeekClick(); // Initializing click listener
}
```

Populating the ListView:

```
public void populateWeekList()
{
    String[] weeks = new String [100]; // 100 weeks
    for (int i=0; i<100;i++)
    {
        weeks[i] = "Week"+(i+1);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> weekAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.weeksview,
            weeks
    );

    // R.id.weekTypeList is just a normal TextView.
    ListView weekList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.weekTypeList); 
    weekList.setAdapter(weekAdapter);
}
```

Code for initializing onClickListener and saving the selectedWeek reference:

```
public void initWeekClick()
{
    ListView weekList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.weekTypeList);
    weekList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) 
        {
            if (selectedWeek != null) 
            {
                selectedWeek.setBackgroundColor(0);
            }
            TextView clicked = (TextView) viewClicked;

            // Change clicked TextView color to red.
            clicked.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));

            // Save the selected week reference
            selectedWeek = clicked;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your background is shuffling because when you scroll your ListView `getView()` is called and it consider your current position of TextView(as current *view*) and set background on it as it detect `setBackground()` method at `onClick` listener on it..

First I recommend to create a **Adapter** class `extends ArrayAdapter<?>`

**Solution 1 :**

Use `setTag()` at `onClick` listener on your text view like..

```
text.setTag(position);
```

and above it use `getTag()` and put condition

```
if(holder.text.getTag().equals(position)){
    holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}else{
    holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

**Solution 2 :**

Added this to `onCreate` method

```
    ArrayList<String> _array = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0 ; i <1000; i ++){                       // 1000 value
        _array.add(i+"");                
    }
    list.setAdapter(new  MainAdapter(this, _array));        // pass you list here
```

ArrayAdapter class :

```
public class MainAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    ArrayList<String> _st = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> check = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Context _context;
    public MainAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> _st) {
        super(context,R.layout.main, _st);        // your inflate layout
        this._context = context;
        this._st = _st;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _st.size();
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //---//

        // check if current position is there in arraylist
        if(checking(position)){
            holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }else{
            holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        holder.text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // set background and put value in array list
                holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                check.add(position);

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    // this will check whether current position is there is array list or not and if it there it will break loop and return true
    public boolean checking(int position){
        boolean fine = false;
        for(int i=0; i<check.size();i++){
            if(position == check.get(i)){
                fine = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return fine;
    }       
  }
  public class ViewHolder{
      TextView text;
  }
}
```

I don't how much I am ethical in this code...but as you have specified that you have **100** value.I have tested it on **1000** value and it worked

*I am not expert so let me know if I am wrong somewhere*

Hope it works !!!

Comment: What do you mean by R.id.text? What's the "text" you are refering to?
This has to be dynamic, a user could click any one of the 100 TextViews

Comment: it is id of  `TextView` in your `R.layout.weeksview`

Comment: Which is created 100 times by the Array Adapter, how do I differenciate between them, I've tried passing the clicked view into a reference and thus, logically speaking, I should be accessing only ONE TextView.

Comment: The issue is that the background is changed for multiple Textviews. For example: 

A user clicks "Week1", it is painted red. - So far so good.
However; when you scroll down you'll notice that "Week11", "Week21" "Week31" ... and so on, are also painted.

Comment: i have changed my answer..have a look at it...And please change  variable according to yours..