# ListView show/hide item onClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm facing an annoying problem on Android.

I have a hidden `FrameLayout` with a "check state" on top of an ImageView. When the user clicks on the row, it should get shown or hidden, depending on the actual state.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutSearchGroupItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ulife_gutter"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/ulife_gutter"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/ulife_half_gutter"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ulife_half_gutter">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatFeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/image_radius_transparent_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:tag="chatFeed"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/layoutSearchResultImage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/ulife_ic_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ulife_ic_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/alt_activity_picture"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/ulife_max_height"
            app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/ulife_corner_avatar_radius"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/luiz_back" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameSelectedUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ulife_ic_tiny_size"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ulife_13_gutter"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ulife_13_gutter"
            android:animationCache="false"
            android:background="@drawable/border_radius_5_green"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/ulife_ic_tiny_size">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ulife_13_gutter"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/ulife_13_gutter"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="textChatFeedCount"
                android:text="√"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/ulife_paragraph_small_size" />
        </FrameLayout>


        </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSearchResultInfoContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ulife_gutter">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Carlos Silva"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/ulife_paragraph_size"
            android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textInstitute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Instituto Chico Chavier"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/ulife_paragraph_size"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My onItemClickListener:

```
listResultsPeopleContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SearchPeopleDetailAdapter searchPeopleDetailAdapter = (SearchPeopleDetailAdapter) listResultsPeopleContainer.getAdapter();
            SearchUserReceiver user = searchPeopleDetailAdapter.getItem(position);

            Boolean addUser = true;
            for (SearchUserReceiver userReceiver : selectedUsers) {
                Logger.e(user.type.toString() + " selectedUsers");
                if (userReceiver.id == user.id) {
                    addUser = false;
                }
            }
            if (addUser) {
                ((FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frameSelectedUser)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                selectedUsers.add(user);
            } else {
                SearchUserReceiver userReceiverRemove = null;
                ((FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frameSelectedUser)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                for (SearchUserReceiver userReceiver : selectedUsers) {
                    if (userReceiver.id == user.id) {
                        userReceiverRemove = userReceiver;
                    }
                }
                if (userReceiverRemove != null) {
                    selectedUsers.remove(userReceiverRemove);
                }
            }

            ((SearchPeopleActivity) getActivity()).usersSelected = selectedUsers;
        }


    });
```

I'm aware of the Android recycling view process, but I can't find out how to avoid this issue.
Below are the print of the 1st item selected.

[image]

The second print is the 11th item on the list, which WAS NOT CLICKED, it came as checked !

[image]

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33143268/2553431) answer

Answer (score 0):

You must re-set the `FrameLayout` visiblity in `getView()` method.

Comment: Yeah, I know, the problem is, I don't know the state of the Layout in the getView, because it gets recycled. So, if I always hide, if I click the first row and scroll all way down and all way up, it will be invisible.

Comment: You can add a boolean variable in your Model data, to indicate the visibility of the Item... and depending on this boolean you show/hide your frame.