# Multiple SeekBars in Adapter, only last SeekBar updates

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-seekbar

I have a ListView which has a SeekBar in each row. the size of the list and therefore the number of SeekBars will vary.

I've set a SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener and from that i update a TextView based on the integer the SeekBar is displaying.

The problem is that only the last SeekBar in the list seems to update from the SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.

How can i make all of the SeekBars work?

Thanks in advance.

```
private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<?> list;            

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> list) {

            super(context, R.layout.monitoringrowlayout);
            Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;               

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monitoringrowlayout, parent, false);

            final int pos = position;               

            Log.e(TAG, "list size in adapter = " + list.size());

            String record = list.get(position).toString();
            rowView.setTag(record);
            String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
            Log.e(TAG, "itemin record = " + itemsInRecord.length);
            String[] recordItem = new String[itemsInRecord.length];

            for (int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++) {

                recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];

                Log.e(TAG, "recordItem[x]" + x + " " +recordItem[x] );

            }

            recordItem[0] = recordItem[0].replace('[', ' ').trim();     
            recordItem[3] = recordItem[3].replace(']', ' ').trim(); 

            TextView description =  (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowmonitoringdescription);
            description.setText(recordItem[1]);

            rating =  (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowmonitoringrating);                

            sb = (SeekBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.seekbarmonitoring);
            sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);

            return rowView;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.list.size();
        }

    }// end of adapter class

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        upDateTextBox(progress);

    }
};    

private void upDateTextBox(int progress){

    rating.setText(String.valueOf(progress));       

}
```

Comment: obviously because you are setting `rating`(the one used for `upDateTextBox`) var in `getView` ... so  `rating` will be always the `TextView` from last `getView` call ... obviously you have to connect the seekbar with textview ... the common way is to use setTag for seekbar with TextView references

Comment: have a look at [my this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33143268/2553431)

Comment: "only the last SeekBar in the list seems to update from the SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener" -- please explain exactly what this means. If you mean that only one `rating` is getting updated, that's what Selvin is referring to.

Comment: ... also there is another problem with this code ... AdapterView  is reusing item's views ... with such code you will not able to get right values after scrolling item out of visible items and back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was obviously going to happen.

Since `sb` will always be the "last" SeekBar, and `rating` will be always the "last" rating TextView.

Change your code:

```
    private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<?> list;


    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> list) {

        super(context, R.layout.monitoringrowlayout);
        Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monitoringrowlayout, parent, false);

        final int pos = position;


        Log.e(TAG, "list size in adapter = " + list.size());



        String record = list.get(position).toString();
        rowView.setTag(record);
        String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
        Log.e(TAG, "itemin record = " + itemsInRecord.length);
        String[] recordItem = new String[itemsInRecord.length];

        for (int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++) {

            recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];

            Log.e(TAG, "recordItem[x]" + x + " " +recordItem[x] );

        }

        recordItem[0] = recordItem[0].replace('[', ' ').trim();
        recordItem[3] = recordItem[3].replace(']', ' ').trim();

        TextView description =  (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowmonitoringdescription);
        description.setText(recordItem[1]);



        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.seekbarmonitoring);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);
        sb.setTag(rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowmonitoringrating));






        return rowView;




    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

}// end of adapter class



    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            upDateTextBox((TextView) seekBar.getTag(), progress);

        }
    };


    private void upDateTextBox(TextView tv, int progress){

        tv.setText(String.valueOf(progress));


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could i ask you how would i pass 2 String values, recordItem[0] and recordItem[3] in getView to updateTextBox?